# how to pass a datatable to a new form in windowsce

Tags: c#, datatable, windows-ce, sqldatareader

I am trying to pass a datatable to a new form, but I am having null reference exception. I dont understand why. SQL is returning many rows and I am sure it is not empty. here is my code

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter dap = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(stringSql, conn);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dap.Fill(dt2);

cariSelection f = new cariSelection(dt2);  // form
f.ShowDialog();
```

What am I doing wrong?

here is the form constructor.

```
public cariSelection(DataTable dt) {
    dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;   // I am getting the null reference exception here
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: I added extra code above. I get the exception in the form constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to run an InitializeComponent() call before you can access any components on the form.

```
public cariSelection(DataTable dt) {
    InitializeComponent() 
    dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;   // I am getting the null reference exception here
}
```